# libcurl clean CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Tags: c, libcurl

Hello what I am trying to do is send post method twice, however when I send it a second time the information from the first time is also being included and I do not want that.

To illustrate what I mean, this is the code that sends using post method. (the handle curl was already created)

```
void process(char* transferBuffer) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/cpp.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, transferBuffer);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
}
```

If I do something like:

```
process("name=John"); - webserver receives name=John
process("name=El"); - webserver receives name=John AND name=El
```

What I want to do is somehow clean previously used data;

Answer (score 0):

> the curl handle was already created ... What I want to do is somehow clean previously used data

All I can say is that if you want to reuse your curl handle - which is a [best practice](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Persistence), you should reset it with [`curl_easy_reset`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_reset.html) before re-setting your options and re-performing the transfer.

*Note that without the complete sample code (including the creation of your curl handle, etc) it is quite hard to provide a detailed answer.*